# Access nested object in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following data structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5749cb4d42f5b8a18912e8c3"),
    "language" : "en-gb",
    "definitions" : {
        "mobileMenuLabel" : "menu",
        "copyright" : "© 2016 Alexander Ward"
    }
}
```

In a react component I'm attempting to render out the copyright text. The component will happily show me what is in 'language' but every time I try to access anything inside 'definitions' I get an error telling me that definitions is undefined.

Here is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from './nav.jsx'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { languagesLoad } from '../../scripts/actions';

export default class Footer extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(languagesLoad());
  }

  render() {
    const { languages } = this.props
    if(languages.isFetching) {
      return(
        <section class="loader">
          <span>Content is loading...</span>
        </section>
      )
    } else {
      const definitions = languages.items.definitions;
      return(
        <footer class="c-global-footer">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <Navigation postion="footer" />
            <div class="c-global-footer_copyright">
              { definitions.copyright }
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>
      )
    }
  }
}

function select(state) {
  const { languages } = state;
  return {
    languages
  };
}

export default connect(select)(Footer);
```

And here is the reducer the data is pulled in from:

```
export function languages(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_LANG :
      return Immutable(state).merge({
        items: action.payload.languages,
        isFetching: false
      })
    case REQUEST_LANG :
      return Immutable(state).merge({
        isFetching: true
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Here is the action which the reducer uses:

```
// Language
export function requestLanguages() {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_LANG
  };
}

export function getLanguages(json) {
  return {
    type: GET_LANG,
    payload: {
      languages: json,
      receivedAt: Date.now()
    }
  };
}

// thunk actions
export function languagesLoad(pageName) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestLanguages());
    return axios.get(API_ROOT + 'lang/en-gb')
      .then(function(response) {
        dispatch(getLanguages(response.data))
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like items is array in your code, so You can access to definitions via index as const definitions = languages.items[0].definitions

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I'm not sure the problem is at the 'items' level as if I console.log(languages.items.definitions) I get: `Object {mobileMenuLabel: "menu", copyright: "© 2016 BBQ Digital Limited", __immutable_invariants_hold: true}`

Comment: Are you sure that languages is Loaded before rendering?, you check only not isFetching condition, but on first render data could be not loaded and error raises

Comment: isFetching is part of the languages items, plus I get the same result if I check for languages.definitions.

Comment: Sorry, my answer below was wrong. Could you show us what exactly `action.payload.languages` is? Is that an Array, a single Object?

Comment: Em, you checked for isFetching, but in else code block condition no one chekcs occur, there is empty object in 'else' block in first render, after data load, console.log can print data, but on first step, no data and error raise

Comment: Sure I've added the actions to the question.

Comment: Thanks @Janom the lack of checks in the else block was causing the problem! It's working now! :)